# PlayerPrefs does not work for HighScore

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I'm not able to save the highscore for my game. It just doesen't display anything at all. What am I doing wrong ? Any help is appreciated :)

The Game-Over trigger works, as it leads the player back to the menu screen. The problem is that the highscore is missing? Im not sure what I'm doing wrong as there are no compiling errors.

**Score-Script:**

```js
var Score : TextMesh;
 private var score : int = 0;
 
 function Awake()
 
 {
     InvokeRepeating("UpdateScore", 0.05, 0.05);
 
 
 }
 //The ingame score-counter works properly
 function UpdateScore()
 
 {
     score += 1;
     Score.text = score.ToString();
 
 }

 //GameOver is getting triggered properly, but the HighScore value is missing from the menu-screen?
 function GameOver()
 {
 
     if(score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highScore"))
     {
         PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highScore", score);
      
 
     }
     Application.LoadLevel("menu");
}
```

**Menu-Script:**

```js
 private var ray : Ray;
 private var rayCastHit : RaycastHit;
 
 var highScore3DText : TextMesh;

 //As mentioned above, the HighScore is not being displayed at all in the menu-screen
 function awake()
 
 {
     highScore3DText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highScore").ToString();
    
 }
 
 function Update () {
 
     if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
 
         ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
 
         if(Physics.Raycast (ray, rayCastHit)) {
 
             if (rayCastHit.transform.name == "playButton") {
 
                 Application.LoadLevel("MainGame");
             } } } }
```

Comment: I don't know if it is just a typo here on SO, but the function Awake needs to have a capital "A" (menu-script)

Comment: omg! That was the problem all along! How could I missed that?!
Thank you soo much! :D